# angular animation use for ng view transition make horizontal scroll

Tags: angularjs, css-transitions

I use angular animation for ng view transition.It works fine, but during the transition from one view to another both horizontal and vertical scroll is shown in the bottom and left side of the browser.

I use bootstrap css in my project too. So the main view is like :

```
<div ng-controller="NavigationController">

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">PROXY SERVER</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li ng-class="iplistActive"><a href="#/ipRanges">IP Address</a></li>
                <li ng-class="blacklistActive"><a href="#/blacklist">Black List</a></li>
                <li ng-class="typelistActive"><a href="#/typelist">Type List</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
            <h1 class="page-header">{{title}}</h1>

                <div data-ng-view="" id="ng-view" class="slide-animation"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

how can I fix that in order to prevent showing scroll bar?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I would like to know the solution for this too...

Comment: the horizontal scrollbar is now ok but the vertical is still shown

Comment: `overflow:hidden` should fix the scrollbar shouldnt it?